# Get rejected value from mysql query

Tags: mysql, select

I want to know if we can get the rejected values from a mysql select query.

eg:

```
SELECT * FROM table where column1 ='value1' and cloumn2 ='value2'
```

This will fetch all data from table where where column1 and column2.
In this some values from databse will not be selected. I want to get these values also. Is this possible.

I tried to use `where column !='value'` but in certain cases this is not applicable.
Any suggestions.

Comment: because of some value has null value , so if you fire "where colname!='value' then it's getting null value row.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table where NOT (column1 ='value1' and cloumn2 ='value2')`

Comment: Your column has 3-4 values, depending on the structure:  (1) a value you like, e.g. 'value1', (2) some other value, e.g. 'value9', (3) no value, e.g. '', (4) NULL.  Which rows are you trying to get?